# How to find the matching records from 2 files in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have two files which contains email_ids. 
1. Test1.txt 
2. Test2.txt

Test1.txt contents are:

`abc@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
mns@gmail.com`

Test2.txt Contents are:

`jpg@gmail.com
joy@yahoo.com
abc@gmail.com
pet@yahoo.com`

Here abc@gmail.com is common id between Test1.txt and Test2.txt. I want to find out such Id's from these 2 files and insert them into one file.

Please suggest. I just need the ID's which are common in between these two files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]; next} $1 in A' file1 file2 > file.new
```

Comment: +1 for idiomatic Awk :) Had to read it carefully :) I'm a bit surprised, though: are you sure Awk is obliged to create an entry for A[$1] given that there is no lvalue access (no assignment)? So the simple fact of indexing should create an entry? This would not be the case in Perl, but Awk's implementation may of course differ.

Comment: Hi @Edward-Baudrez, Yes I am certain of this. "The `in` operator, which tests for the existence of a particular array element, shall not cause that element to exist. Any other reference to a nonexistent array element shall automatically create it." See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02

Comment: So the use of `$1 in A` on the right-hand side is deliberate, otherwise that expression would also create array elements and that would not be desirable..

Comment: @EdwardBaudrez: added this your name has a space.

Comment: The (rather grandiose) term is "*autovivification*", also present though in different ways in `perl`.

Comment: @mr.spuratic: agree; what I wanted to say was that Perl would not create an array element _in this particular case_, because the element is not being assigned to

Comment: @mr.spuratic: On second thought, I'm not sure you can call it autovivification in Perl, because that is only for references. Assigning to a non-existent array element will simply extend that array if it is indexed beyond the end.

Comment: @Scrutinizer: my name used to have a space, indeed. I removed it. Did it cause any problems?

Comment: You're welcome @Edward .  No, no problems, but since I am relatively new here, I did not know how to handle a space in the name, so I found out later, but then I could no longer edit my response..